# Extension for Generic Type `UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>`

Tags: swift, generics, unsafe-pointers

I'd like to create an extension for `UnsafeMutablePointer` that only affects `UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>`...

I understand that these instructions are pertinent, but I'm not sure how:

> When you extend a generic type, you do not provide a type parameter list as part of the extension’s definition. Instead, the type parameter list from the original type definition is available within the body of the extension, and the original type parameter names are used to refer to the type parameters from the original definition.

Basically, I'm trying to use this method:

```
func toSwift(length: Int) -> [Int] {
    var retVal : [Int] = []
    for i in 0..<length {
        retVal.append(Int(self[i]))
    }
    return retVal
}
```

to act on `self` without the `UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>` as a parameter... is this possible?

Comment: How are you getting an `Int` from the `UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>`?  Using `memory`?

Comment: @JAL that method's signature, working, is really `func toSwiftFromData(data:UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>, length: Int) -> [Int] {` and then where you see `self` that's `data`... does that answer the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Swift 3.1 Update

As of Swift 3.1 (available with Xcode 8.3 beta), concrete same-type requirements are now supported. You can now just say:

```
extension UnsafeMutablePointer where Pointee == UInt8 {
    func asArray(withLength length: Int) -> [Int] {
        return UnsafeBufferPointer(start: self, count: length).map(Int.init)
    }
}
```

---

#### Pre Swift 3.1

You *can* do this – although it's not particularly nice. You'll have to create a new protocol in order to 'tag' the `UInt8` type, and then constrain your extension to that protocol. It also doesn't allow you to easily specify that the `Int(...)` initialiser can take a `_UInt8Type` input – you have to implement a hacky 'shadow' method to do that.

```
protocol _UInt8Type {
    func _asInt() -> Int
}
extension UInt8 : _UInt8Type {
    func _asInt() -> Int {
        return Int(self)
    }
}

// Change 'Pointee' to 'Memory' for Swift 2
extension UnsafeMutablePointer where Pointee : _UInt8Type {
    func asArray(withLength length:Int) -> [Int] {
        return UnsafeBufferPointer(start: self, count: length).map{$0._asInt()}
    }
}
```

All in all I'd prefer to keep this fully generic and go with [@AMomchilov's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37978021/2976878). I'm only really adding this for the sake of completion.

Although it's worth noting that having concrete same-type requirements for extensions (`extension Type where Generic == SomeType`) has been proposed [as a part of the Swift Generics Manifesto](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md#concrete-same-type-requirements) – so hopefully this will be possible in a future version of Swift.

Comment: this is awesome and I'll probably change this to best answer in a while. Seems a bit hacky, though... I wonder if this will break at some point. But... great and thanks for providing a working solution!

Comment: @DanRosenstark While it most definitely does look hacky, it's actually taking advantage of some fundamental Swift concepts (protocols & extending existing types with the 'new' functionality that the protocol defines) – therefore I don't see this ever breaking in a future version of Swift (I can't immediately think of any evolution proposals that would affect it either). Although that being said, if this is production code then I would consider making the `_UIntType` protocol `private` (which would also make the extension private).

Comment: Always bear in mind that Swift is still evolving, and there's some neat things that have been listed as a part of the [Generics Manifesto](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md), as already said, concrete same-type requirements for extensions would make this a breeze to implement. Although there isn't yet a formal evolution proposal for it, it looks like something that'll definitely be coming in a future version of Swift.

Comment: There's also a proposal about [improving the generic capabilities of integers](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0104-improved-integers.md) – which could also be helpful for these kind of operations :)

Comment: Thanks. Really fascinating. When I look at the top protocol extension, my first thought is that I have no idea what I'm looking at, but in fact it's actually really clear ("UInt8 now conforms to this one-method protocol, and here is the method body for this one-method which returns Int")! This is pretty amazing, thanks again.

Comment: @DanRosenstark Happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Currently, you can only do this for protocols, not particular classes or structs. You can  make a dummy protocol and extend your class/struct with it, as with [originaluser2's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37978357/3141234).

However, I don't see a reason not to keep this code generic. What do you think of this?

```
extension UnsafeMutablePointer {
    func toArray(withLength length: UInt) -> [Memory] { //Change "Memory" to "Pointee" in Swift 3
        return Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: self, count: Int(length)))
    }
}
```

Comment: That's amazing. So the `[Memory]` is typed?

Comment: @DanRosenstark What do you mean?

Comment: 1) I mean the array returned will be [UInt8]? 2) what does `Memory` mean, or perhaps a link to this keyword? Thank you!

Comment: `Memory` is the generic type parameter of the struct `UnsafePointer`. When you say something like `UnsafePointer<UInt8>`, you're saying "an `UnsafePointer`, for which the generic type parameter `Memory` is specialised to represent `UInt8`. I know it's called `Memory` from https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_UnsafePointer_Structure/index.html (or `Pointee` in Swift 3 https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/unsafepointer)

Comment: The quote in your question even mentions it: "Instead, the type parameter list from the original type definition is available within the body of the extension, and the original type parameter names are used to refer to the type parameters from the original definition"

Comment: Awesome, thanks for explaining all of this! So I could return any type I want, like `[Int]`, too, I suppose?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115346/discussion-between-amomchilov-and-dan-rosenstark).

Comment: Hey there, hope you don't mind but I'm changing the accepted answer to the other one. I really do appreciate the discussion and wish you best of luck here on SO.