# Swift cast object to type and protocol at the same time

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3, swift-protocols

How can I cast a given object to a type and a protocol in order to call some methods that are defined as an extension

For Example:

```
extension Identifiable where Self: NSManagedObject, Self: JsonParseDescriptor {
    func someMethod() { }
}
```

Now I have an object that I retrieved from Core data and I would like to cast it to the above protocols in order to call someMethod on it. I could cast to the protocols using `protocol<Identifiable, JsonParseDescriptor>` , but how can I include the NSManagedObejct type in it also?

Thanks

Comment: FYI, this is possible now, you can say `extension Identifiable where Self: JsonParseDescriptor, Self == NSManagedObject {}`

Comment: My original question was centered around casting. Is that possible now? I read somewhere that they were planning an & syntax. Did they do it now?

Comment: "centered around casting" I don't know what this means. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 6):

As of **Swift 4**, it is now possible to make mentioned cast directly without tricky workarounds. The task is accomplished similarly as we do protocol composition:

```
var myVar = otherVar as! (Type & Protocol)
```

No more need for extensions and bridge protocols.

Comment: I still get the same error. value as? (MyProtocol & Protocol)

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for it called a *concrete same-type requirement*. Unfortunately, it's not yet possible in Swift.

See ticket [SR-1009](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1009) and [SR-1447](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1447) for details. You should also checkout [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37978357/3141234)

In the mean-while, you can extend `NSManagedObject` with a dummy protocol with the methods you need:

```
protocol _NSManagedObject {
    //the methods you want
}

extension NSManagedObject: _NSManagedObject {}

extension Identifiable where Self: _NSManagedObject, Self: JsonParseDescriptor {
    func someMethod() { }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I can do this, but unfortunately I'll have to refactor a lot in order to get this to work. It doesn't make sense that Swift allows you to create a constrained protocol extension by mixing types and protocols but doesn't allow us to cast to it. Wierd

Comment: Yeah, this is one of Swift's biggest missing features, IMO. Then again, no other language (that I know of) allows for this level of type-safe class extensiblity, in the first place.

Comment: absolutely! I do appreciate this extensibility but I think they should have prevented mixing of types and protocols if casting was not possible since you can never really call these methods back. Thanks for your help