# Swift3: type inference inside generic extension

Tags: arrays, swift, extension-methods, concatenation, swift3

I need to do something like this:

```
extension Array { 
    func flat() -> Element { return self.flatMap { $0 } }
}
```

But there is problem with type inference:

> 'flatMap' produces '[SegmentOfResult.Iterator.Element]', not the
>   expected contextual result type 'Element'

**Edit:** Usage example:

```
[[1,2],[3,4,5],[6]].flat()
```

should produce `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` which is the same as:

```
[[1,2],[3,4,5],[6]].flatMap { $0 }
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the function? What should the result of `[1, 2, 3].flat()` be?

Comment: @MartinR fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a look at the [`flatMap(_:)`](http://swiftdoc.org/v3.0/protocol/Sequence/#func--flatmap-segmentofresult_-sequence_-noescape-self-iterator-element-throws-segmentofresult) signature,

```
extension Sequence {
    // ...
    public func flatMap<SegmentOfResult : Sequence>(_ transform: (Self.Iterator.Element) throws -> SegmentOfResult) rethrows -> [SegmentOfResult.Iterator.Element]
    // ...
}
```

you'll see that it returns a `[SegmentOfResult.Iterator.Element]`, where `SegmentOfResult` is the type that is returned from the function you pass it. This isn't necessarily the same type as `Element` (as your extension is for *all* arrays), which is why your code fails to compile.

In order to be working with arrays where the elements are sequences, you'll want to constrain your extension so that `Element : Sequence`.

Also, as the function you're passing to `flatMap(_:)` is an identity transform (it just returns the element it receives as input), you'll want to change the return type to `[Element.Iterator.Element]` (an array of the inner element).

```
extension Array where Element : Sequence {
    func flat() -> [Element.Iterator.Element] {
        return self.flatMap { $0 }
    }
}
```

Although that being said, I see no reason why this shouldn't be an extension of `Sequence`:

```
// An extension for a sequence of sequences
extension Sequence where Iterator.Element : Sequence {

    // returns an array of the inner element type (an array of the element of the element)
    func flat() -> [Iterator.Element.Iterator.Element] { 
        return self.flatMap { $0 }
    }
}
```

(However, I don't really see the need to create an extension for this in the first place – `array.flatMap{$0}` isn't exactly lengthy!)

Comment: W.r.t. last paragraph: or, as another native alternative (as previously discussed in a thread I can't find now :), `Array(array.joined())`. Ninja-edit: as discussed in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39115192).

Comment: & what if I'd like to use `extension Array where Element : Array`?

Comment: @marek094 `Array` isn't a protocol – so that isn't possible (you cannot conform to a concrete type). What you'd be looking for is `extension Array where Element == Array`, which is a [concrete same-type requirement](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md#concrete-same-type-requirements), which Swift currently doesn't support (there are solutions to work around it that involve tagging with protocols (see for example [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37977817/extension-for-generic-type-unsafemutablepointeruint8)), but that isn't particulary pretty).

Comment: One way (sort of..) to achieve an extension for 2D arrays is to constrain the `Element` to `Collection`, and constrain `Element.Index` and `Element.IndexDistance` to be `Int` (see for example [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39179660/swift-2d-array-generic-extension-issue-accessing-2nd-dimension)) – but this won't be exclusive to 2D arrays (just arrays of collections, where those collections are indexable by `Int`), and may require more constraints to do certain things. But for this case, I see no reason in making the extension for 2D sequences, as that's how `flatMap(_:)` is done

Comment: @Hamish Thank you for an explanation!

Comment: @marek094 Happy to help :)